# highlighting multiple buffers in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have couple of highlighting `elisp` files which do amazing job of highlighting `similar words` and jumping back and forth in them. 
But at times I have a `.h` and `.cpp` open and I want to be able to highlight the variables or functions in both of them when they are open side by side.

I tried searching for such packages but couldn't really find anything. Does anyone have such a system or information to such a system which highlights all the same words in visible buffers in emacs ?

Comment: I assume you want something that sounds like this -> M-x highlight-word-all-visible-buffers.  You type in text (or regexp?) and then it does its magic?  What would the user do to "clear" the highlighting? This sounds like a fun elisp challenge.

Comment: I do see this... http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/

Comment: I also see this (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HiLock) which is probably the behavior you want - but applied to all buffers (only visible buffers?).

Comment: Yeah, applying to all buffers is bad because at a time I have like 20-30 buffers open. It would make emacs and my editing slow

Also, I do use highlight symbol but it doesn't solve the thing I am looking for. 

Thats a bad thing because I don't get to use what I need. But hey, its the exact time I start programming my emacs by myself !!

Comment: anyhow, do let me know in case you see something similar. Thanks !

Comment: An almost identical (later) question on emacs.stackexchange.com with multiple interesting answers: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16659/highlight-regexp-in-multiple-buffers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can highlight and unhighlight *multiple buffers* at the same time, in various ways, using library [**Highlight**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary).

You can highlight or unhighlight regexp matches within the active region or the whole buffer, for each of the buffers you choose. You can use text properties or overlays for the highlighting, with property `face` or `mouse-face`.

You can get library `highlight.el` from [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el) or from [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/highlight).